# BASH: Remove newline for multiple commands

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I need some help . I want the result will be

```
UP:N%:N%
```

but the current result is

```
UP:N%
:N%
```

this is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
UP=$(pgrep mysql | wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ];
then
    echo -n "DOWN"
else
    echo -n "UP:"
fi

df -hl | grep 'sda1' | awk ' {percent+=$5;} END{print percent"%"}'| column -t && echo -n ":"

top -bn2 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \awk 'END{print 100 - $1"%"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) in your first sentence (notice you're creating a subshell in this way):

```
echo -n $(df -hl | grep 'sda1' | awk ' {percent+=$5;} END{print percent"%"}'| column -t ):
```